# activemq message visibility

Tags: activemq-classic

Is there  way i can change the message visibility in activemq something like amazon SQS.
The ticket was raised but i guess closed without implementation(https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-3229).
I want activemq to retain the message after one consumption with session configured as ActiveMQSession.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE but the visibilty of the message set to false so that no other consumer can consume it until the message is not deleted from the activemq(consume it with session ActiveMQSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE) or there is a timeout.

Regards,
Arijit

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is not required:

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/activemq-users/201204.mbox/%3C1333459897591-4528785.post@n4.nabble.com%3E